# How to add default option like "Choose Country" in my boostrap or Java option

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I'am trying to add default option like "Choose Country" in select option in My ASP.NET WEB API.
But I don't know how to do.
I tried to put between select in my boostrap like you see in my code but not showing when I start my page. I can see only countries. I tried even in my Javascript and the same there. And I want to run an alert message when a user
forgot to chose a country I mean if the value is "choose country". Thank you in advance!

```
<label for="Modell">Countries</label>
<select id="Countries" class="form-control">
<option value="" disabled selected>Choose Country</option>    
</select>
```

And my java code is

```
function Countries() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/Api/Countries",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (result) {
                    $.each(result, function (key, value) {
                        $("#Countries").append($("<option></option>").val(value.CountryId).html(value.CountryName));
                    });
                }
            });

        }
```

Comment: Where exactly did you put this html, coz it should work like it is. And btw if you want users to select the `Choose Country` option, remove the disabled attribute from it.

Comment: @gaganshera than you for your response, I don't know why it's not working but I solved it by other solution